# How to define a class name based on specific page in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a body class name based on a specific page in php. What I need to do is first define a variable and then check if the variable exists, and then if it exists display that one, otherwise if it is something else, then do something else, or if nothing then do not show any.

```
<body<?php if (defined('PAGE_KEY') && var == "homepage") echo " class=\"homepage\"";
           elseif (defined('PAGE_KEY') && var == "page3") echo " class=\"page3\"";
           elseif (defined('PAGE_KEY') && var == "page12") echo " class=\"page12\""; ?>>
```

This code will be located in my `head.php`.

My thought was to first check if variable was defined and if so then check what the variable was defined as and then based on that variable it will display a respective class.

The goal is for example on the page12 for the body tag to look like this:

```
<body class="page12">
```

But for example for the body tag on page55 (which I don't want to show a class for) to look like this:

```
<body>
```

In doing so I am able to now define css specifically for a page within the header where the body tag happens to be located.

Problem is first I don't know how to define the variable in the page, and second I don't know exactly how to write the php code above properly.

Attempt, for example on page12 I would have this code:

```
<?php PAGE_KEY = "page12" ?>
```

This code would be for example located in `page12.php`.

Also keep in mind, that the variable will come AFTER the body tag.

I also thought of trying to see what the page URL is but I think that's just making things too complicated.

---

---

---

Based on @Jordi's suggestion, how about this:

```
    <body class="<?php echo PAGE_KEY ?>">
```

on `head.php`.

And then on `page12.php`, this:

```
<?php PAGE_KEY = "page12" ?>
```

and for example on `page5.php` this:

```
<?php PAGE_KEY = "page5" ?>
```

so that on those respective pages the body tag shows this:

on `page5.php`:

```
    <body class="page5">
```

and on `page12.php` the body tag will show this:

```
    <body class="page12">
```

Is this right?

---

@Jose made this suggestion, is this correct?

for example, on `page12.php`, to define the variable as 'page12', this:

```
<?php define("PAGE_KEY", "page12"); ?>
```

Is that what you were suggesting to do?

---

---

---

Ok! This problem is solved. I just needed to add in the code in the individual pages **before the `head.php` include** so I could define it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What can your script use to know that it's on `homepage` vs `page3`? Is it the URL? if so, what does it look like on each of those pages?

Comment: I only need it for three pages only. The rest of the pages I do not want any class defined for on the body tag.

Comment: I'd go with just `<body class="<?php echo PAGE_KEY ?>">`. Even if you don't need a `.page55` body class there's no harm into having it.

Comment: Create array ... check if `PAGE_KEY` exists as key in array and output that value. Much less complicated than multiple `if`

Comment: can you show me how to do the array?

Comment: I will manually define the variable `PAGE_KEY`, which I could name anything (like `kdsjhgfs`, it's just a variable), in the body content of the pages I want to show it.

Comment: Jose can you write that as a solution? So I can see what you're trying to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and define a constant like this :

```
<?php
define( "PAGE_KEY","homepage" );
?>
.
.
.
<body<?php echo " class=\"" . constant( "PAGE_KEY" ) . "\""; ?>>
```

For another page :

```
<?php
define( "PAGE_KEY","page5" );
?>
.
.
.
<body<?php echo " class=\"" . constant( "PAGE_KEY" ) . "\""; ?>>
```

You only change the constant, the rest  is the same for every page.

Edit #1:

```
<body
  <?php
  define( "PAGE_KEY","homepage" );
  echo " class=\"" . constant( "PAGE_KEY" ) . "\"";
  ?>
>
```

Edit #2:

```
<?php
define( "PAGE_KEY","homepage" );
?>
.
.
.
<?php
include( "head.php" >
?>
```

Now, **head.php** is something like this :

```
echo "<body class=\"" . constant( "PAGE_KEY" ) . "\">";
```

Comment: Looks simple, I will go try this. Please note that the variable will come after the <body> tag, will this be fine? I will go try it now though.

Comment: Update: It works, but only if `<?php define( "PAGE_KEY","homepage" ); ?>` comes **first**, problem is the only way for it to come first is if I put it in `head.php` which means I can't make different variables for different pages like I need to.

Comment: Yes, so how can I do this since the `<body>` is in the `head.php` which means that any defining code has to come *after* the `<body>` tag?

Comment: I can't do that because the `<body>` tag is in `head.php` - it is the same for all pages.

Comment: OH. I forgot. The `head.php` has to be INCLUDED in the page. So then I just put it ABOVE the INCLUDED `head.php` inside `page5.php`. I think this is the solution! Let me try and come back to let you know if it worked.

Comment: what a silly mistake I had made. Thank you for the update! Your code WORKS.

Comment: I would like to upvote but I need 15 rep first :) Chose as correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this.

```
<?php
//each page and its class. Many pages can share the same class. If a page doesn't
//have a class, don't include it.
$classes = [
    'homepage'=>'home_class',
    'page1'=>'base_class',
    'page2'=>'home_class',
    'page3'=>'special_class'
];

//Adjust this from one page to the next
$this_page = 'homepage';

//get the class corresponding to current page, or '' if no class
$this_class = isset($classes[$this_page])? $classes[$this_page] : '';
?>
//insert the class for this page.
<body class="<?=$this_class ?>">
```

You can improve on it by moving the `$classes` array to another file (eg a config file) and including it in all your pages.  This way you don't have to rewrite the array on every page (a bad idea because difficult to make a change, easy to make a mistake)

Comment: I'm not sure how I define the page? For example, how does it know that presently I am on `page5.php` so that it should create a class `page5` in the body tag?

Comment: Look at my first comment under your question. I need more info to help you figure that out

Comment: More info: I have three pages and only those 3 pages do I want the body to have a class for. Other pages the body will have no class. The `<body>` tag is in `head.php`. Does that help?

Comment: I understand that you have 3 pgs now (will it be 3pgs forever?). What I need is a way for the script to know which page it's on. This could be the URL for instance. Please read my Q under your comment again.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez, just saw your comment, yes that was what I thought. So that is why I wanted to define the page key within the specific page as the way for it to know what page it is on so like if it is `page5` then it knows that because on `page5.php` I would have defined a variable telling it so.

Comment: In that case, what I posted will work. Just change `$this_page='homepage'` with the new values on the different pages

Comment: @BeetleJuice, ok, so there are only three pages now. I figure if I needed to add another page I could just add them in later. For now there are 3 pages and thoat however will probably not change. As for the other part of your comment,

Comment: yes, I just need to know how to define the variable for example `page5` variable, what is the code I will insert on `page5.php` so that it knows that it is `page5`?

Comment: Change just one line: `$this_page='page5'`; and make sure there is a `page5` key with its matching class in the `$classes` array.

Comment: I mean, what code do I put inside the page (comes **after** the `<body>` tag) to define the variable for that specific page?

Comment: Have you tried what I posted? You don't need to define the variable after the body tag. PHP allows you to define it anywhere before you use it. `$this_page='page5'` defines it. To use it and set the class, look at the last line in my code sample.

Comment: I want to say thank you, your code probably works but the other poster made a simpler and more straightforward answer that answers directly. I was having trouble understanding what code to put on the `page5.php` from your code but I got it working from @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez 's answer.